# pdfTeX cannot handle a new package?

Tags: xetex, pdftex, packages

## Background

I am using a package called "poker" from MIT to draw some poker hands. I have put this package to `~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/`.

Documentation: [Documentation](http://web.mit.edu/foley/games/Arcadia/sr/poker/poker-doc.pdf)

`.sty` file: [sty file](http://web.mit.edu/foley/games/Arcadia/sr/poker/poker.sty)

## Problem

I can only compile my `.tex` file with XeTeX and XeTeX is slooooow. I also want to title page to be nicely formatted using pdfTeX.

When I use pdfTex (txs:///pdflatex), I will have errors on all commands of this package saying `Undefined control sequence.`;

When I use XeLaTeX, it works (txs:///xelatex).

Can I use both interpreters? What should I do?

## Screenshots

This is the successful output. Look at the section title and page header. They are not bold.
[image: This is the successful output. Look at the section title. It is not bold.]

This is what is should be using pdfTeX. Section title and page header are bold:
[image: This is what is should be using pdfTeX.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package `poker` uses PostScript (as does, for example, `pstricks`). You have to use it with the classical way of compilation: `latex`, `dvips`, `ps2pdf` (or Adobe Distiller).
It's possible to use `xelatex` but `xelatex` is always very (very) slow with all the packages which use PostScript (I don't know the reason).